# TextView disappears after it gets updated, it is not null

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView that gets updated inside a `Try` `Catch` block. I can see the updated text show up for a second and then it disappears from the emulator. I have no idea what is causing this unwanted behavior. My first guess was that the value was null so i wrote a quick line to the Log and called the `getText()` method of the TextView and confirmed that my data value is in good shape and is not null. My second try was to go into the XML file and check if there is nothing conflicting with my views. As i just started developing this application, i have not updated the UI what so ever just basically dragged components in the screen to initialize them. I have another TextView with the same color property and the same background image, and it shows up fine. Removed the layout components and just left out both of my TextViews. One shows up and the other one does for a second and then it disappears.

**The Function That Updates The TextViews**

```
private void setDateTime() {
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone, locale);
        Date currentDateTime = calendar.getTime();
        String dateTime = currentDateTime.toString();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The current date and time is: " + dateTime);

        SimpleDateFormat inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd");
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        try {
            Date parsedDate = inputDate.parse(dateTime);
            mCurrentDateTV.setText(dateFormat.format(parsedDate));
            mCurrentTimeTV.setText(timeFormat.format(parsedDate));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The current date is: " + mCurrentDateTV.getText() + " and the time is " + mCurrentTimeTV.getText());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error parsing date and time: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

**The XML Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_current_weather_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <com.nvanbenschoten.motion.ParallaxImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_current_weather_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_current_weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_current_weather_settings_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_current_weather_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fragment_current_weather_icon"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The Log File**

`03-22 00:46:09.346 7818-7818/com.xxcanizeuxx.clima_tact/CurrentWeatherFragment: The current date and time is: Thu Mar 22 00:46:09 EDT 2018`

`03-22 00:46:10.009 7818-7818/com.xxcanizeuxx.clima_tact/CurrentWeatherFragment: The current date is: Thu, Mar 22 and the time is 12:46 AM`

As you can see there is data in my TextView.

Comment: you should try it on a real mobile device. Sometimes it happens in emulators.

Comment: Can you try hiding all other views. I see that the other views have no layout positions, and they may be covering your textview.

Comment: @lionscribe Do you want to answer the question? You were right, the loss of layout positions were interfering with the TextView being displayed :D. Learning experience thank you!

Comment: ParallaxImageView is having match parent which is hidding your view as @lionscribe says make it wrap

Comment: Yup. My mistake was just working on the code without actually making adjustments to the UI and expecting results. Since i just basically initialized everything to be able to work on it but never bothered to set up my views correctly.